# How do I unzip a .zip/.rar file in Node.js into a folder

Tags: node.js

I am using zlib along with fstream now for zipping and sending to the client, Now I need to unzip an archive(which may contains sub folders) into a folder maintaining the folder structure. How do I do that?

Comment: Hello May I know how to compress an entire folder into a single zip file. I am trying to use fstream.Reader({path:"E:\\d data\\electron\\Applications\\FirstApp\\js\\temp\\",type:"Directory"})
 .pipe(new tar.Pack())
 .pipe(zlib.Gzip()) 
 .pipe(fstream.Writer({path:"C:\\Users\\Raina\\AppData\\Local\\Temp",file:'compressed_folder.tar.gz' }));  but I am getting an error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are plenty of node modules that can do this for you. One of them is node-unzip. You can extract a .zip file to a directory as simple as this.

`fs.createReadStream('path/to/archive.zip').pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: 'output/path' }));`

Further reading: https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip

Comment: Can I do the same with zlib without using unzip?

Comment: @Raghav I believe zlib is for handling GZip and not Zip.

Comment: @gpopoteur Hi, I know this post is quite old but it's really helpful for me. Can you tell me how I can know when the whole thing fs.createReadStream('path/to/archive.zip').pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: 'output/path' })); finishes? I want to do something after it finishes :)

Comment: Extract emits the 'close' event once the zip's contents have been fully extracted to disk.

Comment: can we add a return something to this function?

Comment: How will i get  unzip directory name?.because  i passed input as archive.zip or any  other  zip file  extension   but when extraction perform   then directory have    file name with out extension   so how will get directory name of unzipped   directory  using  program

Answer (score 2):

Rar is a closed-source software. The only way you can do it -- install command-line rar (rar.exe or linux version of rar, which is available on most platforms) and call it by means of this:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec("rar.exe x file.rar", function (error) {
    if (error) {
     // error code here
    } else {
      // success code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this amazing module http://node-machine.org/machinepack-zip

for uncompress a zip file with directory structure inside zip

```
var Zip = require('machinepack-zip');
```

// Unzip the specified .zip file and write the decompressed files/directories as contents of the specified destination directory.

```
Zip.unzip({
   source: '/Users/mikermcneil/stuff.zip',
   destination: '/Users/mikermcneil/my-stuff',
}).exec(callbackSuccess, callbackFail );
```

for download remote file and unzip you can use this code:

```
        var fs = require('fs');
    var unzip = require("unzip2");
    var tar = require('tar');
    var zlib = require('zlib');
    var path = require('path');
    var mkdirp = require('mkdirp'); // used to create directory tree
    var request = require("request");
    var http = require('http');
    var zip = require("machinepack-zip");



    for (var i = 0; i < _diff.length; i++) {
        request(constants.base_patch +"example.zip")
            request = http.get({ host: 'localhost',
                                     path: '/update/patchs/' +  "example.zip",
                                     port: 80,
                                     headers: { 'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate' } });

            request.on('response', (response) => {
                var output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + "/tmp/" +"example.zip");

                  switch (response.headers['content-encoding']) {
                    // or, just use zlib.createUnzip() to handle both cases
                    case 'gzip':
                      response.pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: __dirname }));
                      break;
                    case 'deflate':

                      response.pipe(zlib.createInflate()).pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: __dirname }));
                      break;
                    default:
                      response.pipe(output);
                      break;
                  }
            })

            request.on('close', function(){
                zip.unzip({
                    source: __dirname + "/tmp/" + "example.zip",
                    destination: __dirname,
                }).exec({
                    error: function (err){
                     alert("error")
                    },

                    success: function (){
                     //delete temp folder content after finish uncompress 
                    },
                });
            })
    }
```

note : remove unnecesary modules.

Answer (score 0):

Use node js decompress-zip, first install it with npm:

```
npm install decompress-zip --save
```

Then you have to require it:

```
const DecompressZip = require('decompress-zip');
```

Finally you can use it in the following way:

```
let unzipper = new DecompressZip( absolutePathFileZip );
```

The directory to be extracted must be specified:

```
unzipper.extract({
    path: pathToExtract
});
```

Additional you can use the following for better control:

Handle Error:

```
unzipper.on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('event error')
 });
```

Notify when everything is extracted

```
unzipper.on('extract', function (log) {
    console.log('log es', log);
});
```

Notify "progress" of the decompressed files:

```
unzipper.on('progress', function (fileIndex, fileCount) {
    console.log('Extracted file ' + (fileIndex + 1) + ' of ' + fileCount);         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looking for async-await way syntax:

```js
const request = require('request');
const unzip = require('unzip');

await new Promise(resolve =>
            request('url')
                .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('path/zipfilename'))
                .on('finish', () => {
                    resolve();
                }));

await new Promise(resolve =>
            fs.createReadStream('path/filename')
                .pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: 'path/extractDir }))
                .on('close', ()=>{
                    resolve()
                }));
```