# How to extract .rar files in node.js?

Tags: node.js, module, extract, rar

I am trying to extract .rar files using node.js in windows 8.1. Is there any good way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would refer to the following response http://stackoverflow.com/a/27450112/2824993

Comment: @cdurth is there any other way that doesn't use Rar, which is a closed-source software? I already tried this but another problem emerging is that: After I download a rar file using http.get, and run that code, it says that file I attempt to extract is not a rar file while it's clearly a rar file

Answer (score 5):

[node-unrar-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-unrar-js) is a Rar extractor in JavaScript (TS to be exact), based on the original source code. Unlike Unrar, it does not require external software to be installed on the system.

I managed to extract a .rar file on Linux using the following code.

```
import { createExtractorFromFile } from 'node-unrar-js'

async function extractRarArchive(file, destination) {
  try {
    // Create the extractor with the file information (returns a promise)
    const extractor = await createExtractorFromFile({
      filepath: file,
      targetPath: destination
    });

    // Extract the files
    [...extractor.extract().files];
  } catch (err) {
    // May throw UnrarError, see docs
    console.error(err);
  }
}

// Files are put directly into the destination
// The full path of folders are created if they are missing
extractRarArchive("/path/to/archive.rar", "~/Desktop/files");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.
Your example helped me understand better.
Only example in docs is about .extract and not the createExtractor methods.
I will try to add an answer for someone who wants to flatten the extracted files (ignore the dir scructure.)

Answer (score 3):

```
var Unrar = require('unrar'),
fs = require('fs'),
archive = new Unrar('t.rar');


archive.list(function(err, entries) {

for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    var name = entries[i].name;
    var type = entries[i].type
    if (type !== 'File') {
        fs.mkdirSync(name)
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    var name = entries[i].name;
    var type = entries[i].type;
    if (type !== 'File') {
        continue;
    }

    var stream = archive.stream(name);
    try {
        fs.writeFileSync(name, stream);
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
});
```

Please check [unrar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unrar) this may help

*This script tested on Linux Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

## RAR

[unrar-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unrar-promise)

```
 const unrarp = require('unrar-promise');   
      unrarp
      .extractAll('rar-file-path', 'extract-directory')
      .then(result => {
        cb(null, result);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        cb(err);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Nodejs doesn't native support Rar compression/decompression, I frustrated with this too so I created a module called `super-winrar` making super easy deal with rar files in nodejs :)

check it out: https://github.com/KiyotakaAyanokojiDev/super-winrar

Example extracting all files and just `package.json` from "project.rar":

```js
const Rar = require('super-winrar');

const rar = new Rar('project.rar');
rar.on('error', error => console.log(error.message));

rar.extract({path: 'extractionDest'}, async (err) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err.message);
  console.log('extract finished!');
});

// works with async/await too;
// will extract only files into array;
const anyAsyncFunction = async () => {
  await rar.extract({path: 'extractionDest', files: ['package.json']});
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use DecompressZip module for extracting zip/rar files.[Documentation and installation of Decompress-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decompress-zip)

```
var DecompressZip = require('decompress-zip');
var unzipper = new DecompressZip(filename)
unzipper.on('error', function (err) {
console.log('Caught an error');
});

unzipper.on('extract', function (log) {
console.log('Finished extracting');
});

unzipper.on('progress', function (fileIndex, fileCount) {
console.log('Extracted file ' + (fileIndex + 1) + ' of ' + fileCount);
});

unzipper.extract({
path: 'some/path',
filter: function (file) {
    return file.type !== "SymbolicLink";
}
});
```

Comment: I don't see any mention of unpacking rar files in the library

Comment: It cant extract rar files.